# Custom Toolbar doesn't show up on first view but does 2nd time shown

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a custom toolbar that I am implementing in my app. I am using a navigation controller for my views. In my first view I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   // Background toolbar image for every View
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"toolbar_iphone1.png"];
 [[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

}
```

The first time the view is shown, the toolbar is the default one and not my custom toolbar. All the views after that have the custom toolbar though. And if I go back to that original view, then the toolbar shows up.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: try the same in `viewWillAppear` method and check.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling `[super viewDidLoad]` in your implementation.

Add it and try again.